# How do I create a specific report on a Watchguard firewall?

Tags: logging, watchguard

I am trying to recover from the Cryptolocker virus, and keep getting blacklisted at CBL. 
I need specific communication data on ports above 1000. 
I do not see a way to setup a specific report of logging options. 
Is this possible to do? I have an x550e.

Comment: Are you running WatchGuard System Manager?

Comment: Yes I run System Manager with logging and reporting...

Answer (score 0):

Each policy should its own logging option. I think the only way is to modify each policy enabling logging.

Comment: Well since logging is enable on all my policies, I suppose the proper question is how do I then create a custom report to refine the data I'm looking for...